# Remove space between table and div

Tags: html, css

Remove space between div and table. Double borders should not come at the right end.

```
table
{
   margin-left: -1px;
   width: 100%;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dilleswari/z6e1c8px/3/)

Comment: Here is the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Dilleswari/z6e1c8px/3/)

Comment: Welcome to the stackoverflow.com. Please make your updates on the question, not in the comments section, and use "How can i ?" or "Please help me with" in your questions. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the code related to div? aren't you asking someone to do that for you instead of stating what problem you have faced so far?

Comment: @pjp: I provided fiddle

Comment: If that's the case, the table snippet you provide here does not serve any purpose and almost every question would just start pointing to a fiddle link isn't it? Fiddle is good for demo but for a question statement point of view, it could be more elaborate and clear about what *problem* you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

Check cellspacing and cellpadding
e.g.

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note: The cellspacing attribute is not supported in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/z6e1c8px/6/

Just a modification to your code. Also I recommend you to avoid using negative values for margin.

Eg:-

```
table{ margin-left: -1px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/z6e1c8px/8/

Doing border-left and border-right zero for the last and first td respectively. And remove margin-left: -1; for the table.

```
table td:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}

table td:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried the same. It is working in Chrome and mozilla. but in IE it   is showing space at right end of the table

Comment: I am getting the same output in IE11 and IE10. As you have given overflow-x: scroll, it is showing a scrollbar. Removing that, gives me the similar results. Can you tell the IE version you checked.

Comment: I'm using IE11. Even we give scroll, in all other browsers there is not extra space. I need the same thing in IE too.

Comment: I don't see the issue. Even if you get space, removing overflow-x: scroll; should resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you wanted.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
div {
  margin: 20px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  -webkit-border-radius: .4em;
  -moz-border-radius: .4em;
  border-radius: .4em;
}
table td {
  border: solid 1px #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
      <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
      <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```